# Initialising a variable in the while expression - not the statement

Tags: java, if-statement

In the expression of a while loop, is it possible to initialise a variable, then use that as part of the expression?

It's probably simpler in code:

```
while (int a = someMethod(), a<b)
```

It would be possible to just add another method, and so have to following:

```
private boolean whileLoopTest() {
    int a = someMethod();
    return a<b;
}

public void originalMethod() {
    while (whileLoopTest()) {
        //...
```

but this doesn't seem as neat.

*EDIT*
I also don't want to directly compare the method to my variable, as it is compared to several variable, and so if would be a long, unreadable mess.  A better example of what I want would be:

```
while (int a = SomeClass.someStaticMethod(), -1<a && a<b)
```

It's not true in my case, but this would be a equally valid question if `someStaticMethod()` took a long time to return - I would only want to call it once.
I'm fairly new to StackOverflow, so I'm not sure if giving other situations where this would apply is what I should be doing.

Comment: What about `for (int a = someMethod(); a < b; ) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: if you do : 
while(a<b){..your code .. a = someMethod(); }

Comment: @KerrekSB That would loop infinitely if `someMethod()` initially returned a value less than `b` (as there is no ForUpadate expression provided). You need `for(int a = someMethod(); a < b; a = someMethod())`.

Comment: @Jeffrey, or more concisely: `for (int a; (a = someMethod()) < b;) {}`

Comment: @Jeffrey: Oh, I didn't understand that the function has to be called each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a;
while((a = someMethod()) < b){
    //do something
}
```

A common use for this is reading from a file:

```
BufferedReader fileIn = ...
String line;
while((line = fileIn.readLine()) != null){
    //do something
}
fileIn.close();
```

/edit
You can do this for your new scenario:

```
int a;
while(-1 < (a = SomeClass.staticMethod()) && a < b) {
    //do something
}
```

Once the left hand portion of the `&&` statement is executed, the return value of `SomeClass.staticMethod()` is stored in `a`, which carries over the the right hand portion of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function directly without using a local variable like this:

```
while ( someMethod() < b) { /* ... */}
```

This, if your method returns intended value. (If you are casting it to a local variable, it's supposed to)

EDIT: For your second question.
Your concern is understandable, but if you are assigning that methods value to a local variable *inside* while loop's boolean expression, in every loop where "While" checks the expression, you are assigning methods' return value to local variable, which means you are calling that method in every iteration. That doesn't change anything from my first answer.

Comment: I've actually got several boolean expressions that use the value of this method, so I wanted to only evaluate it once.  I'll update my question, I hadn't noticed that this would be an ansser to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just *not* assign the value to "a" if you are not using it anyways?
while (someMethod() < b) { doSomething() }
If you actually do need "a" then your alternate solution would not work. The solution then would be either to save it (which I do not consider unneat) or what Kerrek said.